# Get thymeleaf value with JQuery

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, thymeleaf

I have dropdown menu in frontend. It created with bootstrap and thymeleaf. I need to show only names of the object, but chose the ids.
It's not a problem to get a th:text value with JQuery, but I need th:value. And cannot do it.

html code:

```
<div class="btn-group dropdown">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary dropdown-toggle btn-sm" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Enable tollsystem</button>
    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item dropdown-item-disabled-tollsystem"
        id="disabled-tollsystem"
        th:each="myobject:${myobjects}"
        th:if="${myobject.disabled == true}"
        th:text="${myobject.name}"
        th:value="${myobject.Id}"
    ></a>
</div>
```

JQuery code:

```
$("body").on("click", ".dropdown-item.dropdown-item-disabled-tollsystem", function (event) {

    var system = $(this).text();

    console.log(system);

});
```

`var system = $(this).text();` gets the name. How can I get the id?

Comment: $(this).val() shows null

Comment: you can use `$(this).attr('id')`

Comment: please mark my answer as answered :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
 $(this).attr('id')
```

Enjoy

Answer (score 1):

The `onclick` event listener does not work on `select` you can try this instead:

```
$('body').on('change', '.dropdown-item.dropdown-item-disabled-tollsystem', function() {
  alert($(this).val());
}
```